# Is it possible to run a bash script without sudo within a Nodejs that is started with sudo?

Tags: node.js, bash, sudo

Can a

```
 sudo node app.js
```

spawn/fork a

```
 ./myScript.sh
```

that uses only default user instead of sudo?

The script runs an application that must not be run from sudo(because CUDA can't find libnvrtc.so.10.0 for an application that the script calls) but Nodejs application must use sudo because it needs port-80.

Comment: `sudo -u 'username' ./myScript.sh`

Comment: Why would you run `node` with `sudo`? `sudo` is only for changing the system settings. If you are using `sudo` for something else then you are using it wrong.

Comment: Port 80 needs sudo. Also hek2mgl's comment doesn't work, still port 80 inaccessible without just sude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can pass a `uid` to run the command as. See [docs of child_process.*exec*](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) or [child_process.*spawn*](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options).

Example:

```js
child_process.exec('myScript.sh', {uid: 100})
// Or with .spawn()
child_process.spawn('myScript.sh', [], {uid: 100})
```

Comment: Maybe its about installation of drivers that needs non-sudo environment? Because it only works with non-sudo. Tried your solution but didn't work.

Comment: `100` is just an example, use the *uid* of the user you want to run the script as

Comment: If I connected with a user "myuser" over ssh, is it "myuser" instead of 100?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik use the `id` command to find the numeric *uid*

Comment: It was 1000, tried 1000 in spawn didn't work. Maybe problem is somewhere else.

Comment: But I accept this because it solved part of problem. Thank you.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik It could be that the shell script needs some environment variable that is set in the profile of "myuser"

Comment: are all variables set inside sudo also seen from non-sudo environments?